# Is there a distribution that covers Pareto's law?

Tags: distributions, pareto-distribution

Is there a distribution where (for example) 80% of the results come from 20% of the inputs? (i.e. Pareto's law).  Hmm... there's a tag for Pareto Distribution ... is that the answer?

Comment: Yes. See also Zipf's Laws in language (often considered the discrete equivalent).

Comment: The 80/20 rule can indeed be obtained from a certain Pareto distribution. Although it is not 100% trivial to translate the meaning of 80/20 to properties of a distribution function. Try it out!